# How can I test if line is empty in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script like this:

```
cat file | while read line
do
    # run some commands using $line    
done
```

Now I need to check if the line contains any non-whitespace character ([\n\t ]), and if not, skip it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Since `read` reads whitespace-delimited fields by default, a line containing only whitespace should result in the empty string being assigned to the variable, so you should be able to skip empty lines with just:

```
[ -z "$line" ] && continue
```

Comment: (More accurately, the delimiter used by `read` is determined by the `IFS` variable, which defaults to whitespace. Just unset `IFS` to revert to using whitespace.)

Comment: even simpler: no need to quote line, if you use bash's [[ syntax: `[[ -z $line ]] && continue`

Comment: @pihentagy Umm, that has the same number of characters, and the square brackets `[]` are harder to type than quotes on some international keyboards, and it becomes bash-specific. So maybe not simpler, but an alternative. =)

Comment: (for those newbie like me).   `[ -z "$line" ] && continue` itself is executable. This elegant line is equivalent to `if [ -z "$line" ] ; then continue ; fi`.    By the way, don't forget to set `IFS=" \t\n"` at the beginning unless you don't want to skip 'tab'.

Comment: re. suggested edits that add things, please post your own answers instead – this answers the original question as it is, and works quite universally regardless of the shell, so I don't think the answer is improved by complicating it with more cases for specific shells and/or needs beyond the original question

Answer (score 19):

try this

```
while read line;
do 

    if [ "$line" != "" ]; then
        # Do something here
    fi

done < $SOURCE_FILE
```

Comment: More information about the square bracket notation can be found at [the man page of test](http://man.cx/test)

Comment: disadadvantage here: If the part in the if is long, you get a code difficult to read. Therefore the continue solution is always recommended.

Answer (score 7):

bash:

```
if [[ ! $line =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then
  continue
fi
```

And use `done < file` instead of `cat file | while`, unless you know why you'd use the latter.

Comment: I need smth that would work in both bash and sh. Is there any solution using sh/sed/tr (in case bash is not installed)?

Comment: This worked, the other ([ -z "$line" ] && continue) did not work. I wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

`cat` i useless in this case if you are using while read loop. I am not sure if you meant you want to skip lines that is empty or if you want to skip lines that also contain at least a white space.

```
i=0
while read -r line
do
  ((i++)) # or $(echo $i+1|bc) with sh
  case "$line" in
    "") echo "blank line at line: $i ";;
    *" "*) echo "line with blanks at $i";;
    *[[:blank:]]*) echo "line with blanks at $i";;
  esac
done <"file"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ! grep -q '[^[:space:]]' ; then
  continue
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blank=`tail -1 <file-location>`
if [ -z "$blank"  ]
then
echo "end of the line is the blank line"
else
echo "their is something in last line"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF' file | while read line
do
    # run some commands using $line    
done
```

stole this answer to a similar question:
[Delete empty lines using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed)