# Delete empty lines using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am trying to delete empty lines using sed:

```
sed '/^$/d'
```

but I have no luck with it.

For example, I have these lines:

```
xxxxxx


yyyyyy


zzzzzz
```

and I want it to be like:

```
xxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```

What should be the code for this?

Comment: your sed command looks fine, it should work

Comment: The above command wouldn't work even if you don't have a space/tab but [CR+LF line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: For awk, see: [Remove blank lines in awk](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128328/21471), or [using grep](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1611809/55075), in general, see: [How to remove blank lines from a file in shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101440/21471)

Answer (score 826, accepted):

You may have spaces or tabs in your "empty" line. Use [POSIX classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) with `sed` to remove all lines containing only whitespace:

```sh
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

A shorter version that uses ERE, for example with gnu sed:

```sh
sed -r '/^\s*$/d'
```

(Note that sed does **NOT** support PCRE.)

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr gnu sed doesn't support PCRE at all. it is ERE with `-r`

Comment: OS X needed `sed -i "" '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'` ***`<filename>`***,

Comment: @BernieReiter `^\s*$` will match all "empty" lines, empty here means,  the line contains no chars, or the line contains only empty strings (E.g. spaces). All matched lines will be removed by sed, with the `d` command.

Comment: Perhaps `sed '/\S/!d' file`

Comment: I didn't need the `-r` flag on (GNU sed) 4.9

Answer (score 209):

I am missing the `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NF' file
```

Which would return:

```
xxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```

How does this work? Since `NF` stands for "number of fields", those lines being empty have 0 fields, so that awk evaluates 0 to False and no line is printed; however, if there is at least one field, the evaluation is True and makes `awk` perform its default action: print the current line.

Comment: Whoah. Is even running with BSD's "minimized" version of awk (version 20121220 (FreeBSD). Thanks :-)

Comment: @BernieReiter you are welcome :) Yes, this is a very basic idiomatic thing all awk versions allow.

Comment: And it is so much quicker although - for a quick and dirty test - I am invoking awk twice:

    `$ time (topic companies <data.tpx | awk 'NF' - | awk -f dialog_menu.awk -)    `
    
`real    0m0.006s`
`user    0m0.000s`
`sys     0m0.008s`
    
    `$ time (topic companies <data.tpx | gsed '/^\s*$/d' | awk -f dialog_menu.awk -)    `
    
`real    0m0.014s`
`user    0m0.002s`
`sys     0m0.006s`

Would you know of a nifty way to include this into an awk-script like, e.g., a pattern?
awk '/mypattern/ {do stuff...}'

Comment: @BernieReiter you can say `awk 'NF {do stuff...}'`.

Comment: Note that this will also ignore lines with whitespace only.

Comment: Doesn't work if empty lines also contain carriage return characters `(\r)`

Answer (score 102):

#### sed

- [`'/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`](http://sed.js.org/?gist=0b72f1bd2973a3d6da742f3b9b235508)
- [`'/^\s*$/d'`](http://sed.js.org/?gist=5f78166d34b1ee30a7d460c661145417)
- [`'/^$/d'`](http://sed.js.org/?gist=e69171e6d2a1ae38d145d91fdf32b285)
- [`-n '/^\s*$/!p'`](http://sed.js.org/?gist=65c0d2e8592f042236fe2c564ff8300c)

#### grep

- [`.`](http://grep.js.org/?gist=a486a0ce2f828126fdacb4257372a2f5)
- [`-v '^$'`](http://grep.js.org/?gist=2e7cb6984fe69a8399ab39f895a04190)
- [`-v '^\s*$'`](http://grep.js.org/?gist=8713dcc13da98a0e5d693bc15ecc12fb)
- [`-v '^[[:space:]]*$'`](http://grep.js.org/?gist=b0907fb105eb0e749ad6e35a071e511c)

#### awk

- [`/./`](http://awk.js.org/?gist=60798f22091dedf10be29ea2e67a0783)
- [`'NF'`](http://awk.js.org/?gist=f327d3a56771cb4cf50ab06b84eba975)
- [`'length'`](http://awk.js.org/?gist=52d6258c326e6cf0ad5453d74c9f284f)
- [`'/^[ \t]*$/ {next;} {print}'`](http://awk.js.org/?gist=6f462bbc811366c7c40d60e2711be0f8)
- [`'!/^[ \t]*$/'`](http://awk.js.org/?gist=fb12f7b33bb3efc77eea998c98134a7c)

Comment: These show up correctly in your online tool, but `[]` should *not* be escaped in a bracket expression, so the code here isn't correct for `\[\[:space:\]\]` or `\[ \t\]` - should be `[[:space:]]` and `[ \t]`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for catching that. Those were not from the original author, but came from [Edit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39139322/revisions) when it was changed from regular text to "code", which then "exposed" the `\\` escaping. I have fixed them now.

Answer (score 84):

`sed '/^$/d'` should be fine, are you expecting to modify the file in place? If so you should use the `-i` flag.

Maybe those lines are not empty, so if that's the case, look at this question [Remove empty lines from txtfiles, remove spaces from start and end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562782/remove-empty-lines-from-txtfiles-remove-spaces-from-start-and-end-of-line) I believe that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes. i am modifying a file. *.csv. how should the     -i be placed to the sed command?

Comment: `sed -i '/^$/d'` is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 44):

I believe this is the easiest and fastest one:

```
cat file.txt | grep .
```

If you need to ignore all white-space lines as well then try this:

```
cat file.txt | grep '\S'
```

Example:

```
s="\
\
a\
 b\
\
Below is TAB:\
    \
Below is space:\
 \
c\
\
"; echo "$s" | grep . | wc -l; echo "$s" | grep '\S' | wc -l
```

outputs

```
7
5
```

Comment: No need for `cat`, `grep` takes files as well: `grep . file.txt`

Comment: Yes, I know, but the initial question did not mention whether the source is a file or something else, so the solution is what comes after "|", and before it just an example of a source. Simply to distinguish the solution from the source of lines.

Comment: `grep '\S'` is definitely not portable.  If you have `grep -P` then you can use `grep -P '\S'` but it's not supported on all platforms, either.

Comment: The downside of `grep .` compared to the other solutions is that it will highlight all the text in red. The other solutions can preserve the original colors. Compare `unbuffer apt search foo | grep .` to `unbuffer apt search foo | grep -v ^$`

Comment: @wisbucky grep does not default to color output, but often it's enable via a shell alias or environment variable. Use `grep --color=never .` to override.

Answer (score 19):

Another option without `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc

```
strings $file > $output
```

strings - print the strings of printable characters in files.

Comment: Do you mean `strings` instead of `string` ?

Comment: "For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long..." so very short lines might give you a surprise if you're unaware of this. There is a `--bytes=min-len` option to allow shorter lines.

Answer (score 17):

With help from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562782/remove-empty-lines-from-txtfiles-remove-spaces-from-start-and-end-of-line) and the accepted answer above, I have used:

```
$ sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d; /^\s*$/d' file.txt > output.txt

`s/^ *//`  => left trim
`s/ *$//`  => right trim
`/^$/d`    => remove empty line
`/^\s*$/d` => delete lines which may contain white space
```

This covers all the bases and works perfectly for my needs.  Kudos to the original posters @Kent and @kev

Answer (score 9):

The command you are trying is correct, just use -E flag with it.

```
sed -E '/^$/d'
```

-E flag makes sed catch extended regular expressions. [More info here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: There is nothing in this particular regex which requires the `-E` flag.

Answer (score 5):

You can say:

```
sed -n '/ / p' filename    #there is a space between '//'
```

Comment: .. which means `print all lines except the empty one(s)`and be quiet

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely seeing the unexpected behavior because your text file was created on Windows, so the end of line sequence is `\r\n`.  You can use dos2unix to convert it to a UNIX style text file before running sed or use

```
sed -r "/^\r?$/d"
```

to remove blank lines whether or not the carriage return is there.

Comment: Hi, what is the `-r` flag doing and is it possible to combine it with `-i` to modify the file directly and avoid printing to screen. In addition, I think that this command would also work as `sed -r "/^\r$/d"`

Answer (score 3):

This works in awk as well.

```
awk '!/^$/' file
xxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that using "grep", too:

```
egrep -v "^$" file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use modern Rust tools, you can consider:

- [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

  - `cat datafile | rg '.'` line with spaces is considered non empty
  - `cat datafile | rg '\S'` line with spaces is considered empty
  - `rg '\S' datafile` line with spaces is considered empty *(`-N` can be added to remove line numbers for on screen display)*
- [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd)

  - `cat datafile | sd '^\n' ''` line with spaces is considered non empty
  - `cat datafile | sd '^\s*\n' ''` line with spaces is considered empty
  - `sd '^\s*\n' '' datafile` inplace edit

Answer (score 1):

My `bash`-specific answer is to recommend using `perl` substitution operator with the global pattern `g` flag for this, as follows:

```
$ perl -pe s'/^\n|^[\ ]*\n//g' $file
xxxxxx
yyyyyy
zzzzzz
```

This answer illustrates accounting for whether or not the empty lines have spaces in them (`[\ ]*`), as well as using `|` to separate multiple search terms/fields. Tested on macOS High Sierra and CentOS 6/7.

FYI, the OP's original code `sed '/^$/d' $file` works just fine in `bash` Terminal on macOS High Sierra and CentOS 6/7 Linux at a high-performance supercomputing cluster.

Answer (score -1):

Using vim editor to remove empty lines

`:%s/^$\n//g`

Answer (score -2):

For me with FreeBSD 10.1 with **sed** worked only this solution:

```
sed -e '/^[     ]*$/d' "testfile"
```

inside `[]` there are space and tab symbols.

test file contains:

```
fffffff next 1 tabline ffffffffffff

ffffffff next 1 Space line ffffffffffff

ffffffff empty 1 lines ffffffffffff

============ EOF =============
```

Answer (score -2):

NF is the command of awk you can use to delete empty lines in a file
`awk NF filename`
and by using sed
`sed -r "/^\r?$/d"`

Comment: Both these answers were already given years ago.