# Merge two blank lines into one

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking for a solution of turning file A to file B, which requires merging two blank lines into one.

File-A:

```
// Comment 1
// Comment 2

// Comment 3


// Comment 4



// Comment 5
```

File-B:

```
// Comment 1
// Comment 2

// Comment 3

// Comment 4

// Comment 5
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed), I know how to delete empty lines, I am wondering how to merge two consecutive blank lines into one.

**PS: blank means that it could be empty OR there might be a tab or a space in the line.**

Comment: Do you like to have one blank line between every line, even if there are three blank lines consecutive.  Please give example output.

Comment: I thought I could use a loop for 2+ blank lines situation, so I didn't ask that. You mean there is an answer for 2+ blank lines?

Comment: OK My answer does what I thought you like to do :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^\s+$//' infile | cat -s > outfile
```

`sed` removes any whitespace on a blank line. The `-s` option to `cat` squeezes consecutive blank lines into one.

Comment: This works, thanks. Could it be possible to do the edit "in-place"?

Comment: +1; clever combination of tools, although the syntax is GNU `sed`-specific. A POSIX-compliant alternative: `sed 's/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}$//' file | cat -s > outfile`.

Comment: @Daniel: You'll have to use the standard idiom for working around not being able to perform in-place updating: instead of `> outfile`, use `> /tmp/tmp.$$ && move /tmp/tmp.$$ infile`.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/^\s*\n\s*$//;P;D' file
```

This will convert 2 blank lines into one.

If you want to replace multiple blank lines into one:

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\s*\n\s*$//;ta;P;D' file
```

On reflection a far simpler solution is:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n\s*$//;ta' file
```

Which squeezes one or more blank lines to a single blank line.

An even easier solution uses the range condition:

```
sed '/\S/,/^\s*$/!d' file
```

This deletes any blank lines other than those following a non-blank line.

Comment: Could you please explain `!N;` and `;P;D` part?

Comment: @MarkZar see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) but first see my recent edit for a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution with `awk`:

```
awk '!NF && !a++; NF {print;a=0}' file
// Comment 1
// Comment 2

// Comment 3

// Comment 4

// Comment 5
```

`NF` counts the number of fields; note that a line composed entirely of spaces and tabs counts as a blank line, too.
`a` is used to count blank lines, and if it's more than `1`, skip it.

Answer (score 1):

[**This page**](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/sed.html) might come handy.  TL;DR as follows:

```
# delete all CONSECUTIVE blank lines from file except the first; also
# deletes all blank lines from top and end of file (emulates "cat -s")
sed '/./,/^$/!d'          # method 1, allows 0 blanks at top, 1 at EOF
sed '/^$/N;/\n$/D'        # method 2, allows 1 blank at top, 0 at EOF
```

Comment: This fails if there are `spaces` and or `tabs`. OPs request `PS: empty could also mean that there might be a tab or a space in the line.`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed 'N;s/^\([[:space:]]*\)\n\([[:space:]]*\)$/\1\2/;P;D' file
```

Comment: @Daniel I could look into it if you provide sample input and/or describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS='([[:blank:]]*\n){2,}' -v ORS="\n\n" 1 file
```

I had hoped to produce a shorter Perl version, but Perl does not use regular expressions for its record separator.

awk does not edit in-place. You would have to do this:

```
awk -v RS='([[:blank:]]*\n){2,}' -v ORS="\n\n" 1 file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: A heads-up: Requires an `awk` implementation that recognizes regexes as record separators (non-POSIX), such as GNU `awk`. The trailing `\n\n` in the output is awkward.