# NULLS are loading along with actual data after imported data into hive table

Tags: apache, hive

I am loading from csv file and data is separated by space. After loading data into final table it is loading extra NULLs are an extra row along with actual data.

**Actual Data**

```
 id first_name last_name email gender ip_address

1 James Coleman jcoleman0@cam.ac.uk Male 136.90.241.52

2 Lillian Lawrence llawrence1@statcounter.com Female 101.177.15.130

3 Theresa Hall thall2@sohu.com Female 114.123.153.64

4 Samuel Tucker stucker3@sun.com Male 89.60.227.31

5 Emily Dixon edixon4@surveymonkey.com Female 119.92.21.19
```

**Table creation**

```
create  table serde_sample(id int,first_name string,last_name string,email string,gender string,ip_address string)
  row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties (
  "separatorChar" = "\t"
  )
  tblproperties('skip.header.line.count'='1') 
  ;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/Desktop/files/serde.csv' into table serde_sample;
```

**got an Output**

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

1 James Coleman jcoleman0@cam.ac.uk Male 136.90.241.52  
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

2 Lillian Lawrence llawrence1@statcounter.com Female 101.177.15.130 

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

3 Theresa Hall thall2@sohu.com Female 114.123.153.64    

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

4 Samuel Tucker stucker3@sun.com Male 89.60.227.31  

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

5 Emily Dixon edixon4@surveymonkey.com Female 119.92.21.19  

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I am not sure where it is going wrong. Why extra NULL rows are coming.
Can someone help to resolve this issue

Comment: Is it extra empty lines(\n) in the file? Your Actual data example in the question contains empty rows, this can be the reason

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can we remove nulls if actual data is like this?

Comment: Remove them from file before load or filter all nulls during select

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16414410/2700344