# Removing empty lines with grep as well as [, ], ', and ,?

Tags: sed

```
sed "s/[][,']//g"
```

I used this, but then I have empty lines getting returned. I know that you can use:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

[Delete empty lines using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed)

However, trying `sed "s/[][[:space:]][,']//g"` didn't work as well as other stuff I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is a scripting language; combine the two commands to get the effect you seek.

```
sed "s/[][,']//g;"'/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```